# Add form in sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In my ActiveAdmin app, I need to have a form in the sidebar (only for the show method) that will show a single (for the moment) datepicker. Once user click on the datepicker, the whole page should reload taking into account the date selected (within the show controller).

Any idea on how to add this simple form in a sidebar ?

**EDIT**

I tried the following but I'm not sure how the form can target a dedicated controller other than the current model.

```
sidebar :history, :only => :show do
  form do |f|
    f.input :start_date, :as => :datepicker
  end
end
```

How can a form in a sidebar can target another controller than the one of the current model ?

Comment: It is easier to give a good answer, if you put some code in you question.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have a show controller and don't mean the show action.

make the view into a partial called "whatever" (I call it this)

So, your whatever.erb.html looks like this

```
<%= render "whatever" %>
```

If you use [Jquery Ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), you can add a onSelect function

```
$(".date").datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
            onSelect: function() {
            $('#range_form').submit();          
            }
       }).attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' )
```

If you want a range add a form tag in your view with two date fields, else you just add one

```
<%= form_tag('/range', :id => "range_form", :remote => true) do -%>
   <%= text_field_tag 'from', Date.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),:class => "date"%>
   <%= text_field_tag 'to', Date.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), :class => "date"%>
<% end %>
```

For this you'll have to add a route in your routes.rb

```
match "/range/" => "show#todo_range", :as => :range
```

In your show controller

```
def range
    time_range = ((Date.parse(params[:from]).midnight..Date.parse(params[:to]).midnight)
    @whatever = Whatever.where(:date => time_range)
end
```

Then add a js view to handle the callback

```
$(".maindiv").empty().append(<%=j(render @whatever)%>)
```

I have not tested this exact code, so watch out for typos.

Good luck and comment if I need to edit

Comment: In fact I meant the show controller within the activeadmin's my_model.rb . The datepicker can be directly used within the form but I do not manage to create a dedicated form in the sidebar.